# Gunicorn won't start with can't connect to ('0.0.0.0',443)

Tags: python, gunicorn, redhat

I am getting the following error from gunicorn when I try to bind on port 443:

```
Retrying in 1 second.
Retrying in 1 second.
Retrying in 1 second.
Retrying in 1 second.
Retrying in 1 second.
Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0',443)

or

Can't connect to ('',443)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ports < 1024 are privileged ports.  Give access to process that is binding on that port:

```
setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip /usr/bin/python3.6
```